# What else should I be reading to make better sense of Cyclonopedia?

Tags: suggested-order

I've been *slowly* working my way through Reza Negarastani's fantastic *[Cyclonopedia](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0980544009)* the past few weeks, and while I'm thoroughly enjoying it, I can't help but think there's substantial material that's going over my head.

I know it's been pointed out to me that reading Deluze and Guattari's [*Thousand Plateaus*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0816614024) would be a good start (and I've ordered it), but surely with a work of this density it's not the only reference I can draw on.

Better yet, is there some sort of reference list or 'readers companion' that I could pair with *Cyclonopedia* to get the most out of it?

Edit: Further research has also brought me to Negarastani's excellent [blog](http://blog.urbanomic.com/cyclon/), which is providing me with a ton of links to further explore.

Comment: This is an excellent question, possibly one of the best I've seen on this site, attempting to make use of the specialized knowledge that is gathered here. It's a shame more people aren't upvoting this.

Answer (score 2):

Haven't been able to find any written references that might be of use. However there are two movies that are recommended to watch in combination with reading Cyclonopedia, as they are cited in the book:

- [Trouble Every Day](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0204700/)
- [Begotten](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0101420/)

Answer (score 1):

Not trying to be an open-ended list, but also not exhaustive:

Giles Deleuze: explorations of his theory that standards of value are internal or immanent: to live well is to fully express one's power, to go to the limits of one's potential, rather than to judge what exists by non-empirical, transcendent standards.

- *Difference and Repetition (1968)*

Felix Guattari: The theory of schizoanalysis

- *The Machinic Unconscious: essays in schizoanalysis (1979)*

Deleuze & Guattari:

- *of Capitalism and Schizophrenia: Anti-Oedipus (1972)*
- *A Thousand Plateaus (1980)*

Jean Genet: the continuance of life and nation through art and poetry.

- [The Thief’s Journal](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Thief%27s_Journal)

H.P. Lovecraft: Cthulhu mythos

- “The Call of Cthulhu” (1928)
- “The Dunwich Horror” (1928)
- “The Whisperer in Darkness” (1930)
- *At the Mountains of Madness* (1931)

[Gog and Magog religion and mythology](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gog_and_Magog)

- The Bible
- The Koran
- Jewish Kabbalah

The Meta-Fictional Works and Interviews with Meta-fictional Iranian Scholar Hamid Parsani as facilitated by Reza Negarestani

- [The Parsani Interview](https://www.google.com/amp/s/internalfrontiers.wordpress.com/2013/05/14/nation-is-a-skin-stretched-over-the-bones-of-the-state-an-interview-with-hamid-parsani/amp/)

William Blatty

- *The Exorcist (1971)*

General topics:

- [Zoroastrian religion & mythology](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zoroastrianism)
- [History of Middle-East Oil](https://study.com/academy/lesson/middle-east-oil-history-production.html)
- - [Post-colonial Sudan & life of Ustadh Mahmoud Muhammad Taha](https://www.alfikra.org/page_view_e.php?page_id=2)
- [al Qaeda](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Qaeda)
- [The Global War on Terrorism](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_on_terror) (and “[Bush Doctrine](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bush_Doctrine)”)